# Kafka-connect with sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

These are commands which I am running:-

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties &
bin/kafka-server-start etc/kafka/server.properties &
bin/schema-registry-start etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties &
bin/connect-standalone etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/quickstart-sqlserver.properties &
bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9094 --topic test3-sqlserver-jdbc-ErrorLog --from-beginning
```

I am trying to connect sqlserver using confluent platform(kafka-connect) and facing following issues:

When I am trying to connect to default schema i.e. dbo , connection is built but it is not able to fetch data into the kafka consumer. The connection details that I am using are:

```
name=test-sqlserver-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://********:1433;database=AdventureWorks2012;user=****;password=****
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=ErrorLogID
topic.prefix=test3-sqlserver-jdbc-
table.whitelist=ErrorLog
schema.registry=dbo
```

When I am trying to connect to any other schema, the producer is throwing error, connection details that i am using are :

```
name=test-sqlserver-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:sqlserver://********:1433;database=AdventureWorks2012;user=****;password=****
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=AddressID
topic.prefix=test3-sqlserver-jdbc-
table.whitelist=Address
schema.registry=Person
```

Error :

```
INFO Source task WorkerSourceTask{id=test-sqlserver-jdbc-autoincrement-0} finished
initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:138)

[2017-03-07 17:55:47,041] ERROR Failed to run query for table
TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='Address', query='null',
topicPrefix='test3-sqlserver-jdbc-', timestampColumn='null', 
incrementingColumn='AddressID'}: 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Address'.
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceTask:239)
[2017-03-07 17:55:52,124] ERROR Failed to run query for table
TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='Address', query='null',
topicPrefix='test3-sqlserver-jdbc-', timestampColumn='null',
incrementingColumn='AddressID'}: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
Invalid object name 'Address'. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceTask:239)
[2017-03-07 17:55:53,684] INFO Reflections took 9299 ms to scan 
262 urls, producing 12112 keys and 79402 values  
(org.reflections.Reflections:229)
[2017-03-07 17:55:57,181] ERROR Failed to run query for table
TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='Address', query='null',
topicPrefix='test3-sqlserver-jdbc-', timestampColumn='null', 
incrementingColumn='AddressID'}:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'Address'.
(io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceTask:239)
```

Comment: Address appears to not be accessible by the connector. I'd check your connection string is valid and that the table Address exists.

Comment: Hi I am able to fetch data from table of default schema(dbo) but in case of other schema peron i am not able to fetch data of any table.so why it's connected to only default schema and not able to connect with other schema

Comment: improved question formatting

Comment: I believe the misunderstanding is in the schema.registry property. This property specifies a URL for your schema registry service. To change schemas in your database you need to modify your connection.url